# How do I take real FFT using STM32F407G?

Tags: fft, stm32

I've been trying to use fft for real data in STM32F407G for quite sometime with no luck. However, I when I use cfft function for complex data, it works. But I don't want to process the imaginary part.So my question is - how to use the rfft function in stm32?
Here is the code which I have tried -

```
#include "stm32f407xx.h"
#include "arm_math.h"
#include "arm_const_structs.h"
#include "core_cm4.h"


#define TEST_LENGTH_SAMPLES 32

extern float32_t  ffttestrealip[TEST_LENGTH_SAMPLES];
static float32_t  ffttestrealop[TEST_LENGTH_SAMPLES];

uint32_t fftSize = 32;
uint8_t ifftFlag = 0;
uint8_t doBitReverse = 1;


int32_t main(void)
{
    arm_rfft_fast_instance_f32 *    S;
    arm_rfft_fast_init_f32  (S,fftSize);

arm_rfft_fast_f32   (S,ffttestrealip,ffttestrealop,ifftFlag )   ;
  while(1);                            
}

 /** \endlink */
```

But when I compile this, it says "error: L6047U: The size of this image (83968 bytes) exceeds the maximum allowed for this version of the linker"
When I comment out "arm_rfft_fast_init_f32  (S,fftSize);" , it compiles but I get a wrong result.

Comment: Drop those size limited paid IDEs and toolchains. Download the official STM32 Attolic or OpenSTM32

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep that in mind. But I don't see why my code can be that big?

Comment: @PeterJ_01- and how do I use my code in attolic or openstm32? I'm not  familiar with these eclipse based environments. Also, I don't know how to use cmsis driver in stm32cubemx. If i could use it there, I can easily generate the code for attolic truestudio toolchain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 32k limit is the *binary* limit as opposed to the RAM limit - there is no guarantee that the *binary* for performing the real FFT will be smaller than the complex FFT.

In reality it could be a more optimized algorithm that is more complex, so that it might require less ram / CPU cycles to compute but could still require more (cheaper) operations to complete.

I have run up to a 4096 pt complex FFT on these parts with no trouble

Answer (score 0):

You're using a size limited linker, 32 k is the common size for evaluation versions of IAR and Keil.

You can either pay to get the full size version, or build your code with arm gcc which is free.

Comment: Yeah. But why does this small code require such a large memory? All I want to do is take 32 point real fft.